# Compositor result won't show

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I have problem with compositor.

It doesn't show result in output render until I replug **Image** into **Composite** node.

I am rendering 2 layers, but it show only first layer, without anything modified, until I unplug and plug back into **Image** slot in **Composite** node. Then it shows correctly.

NODE SETUP:
[image]
[image]

**EDIT:**

Result doesn't show in **render output**. In **Viewer** it is visible.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the **[blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34158)** file. Sorry for wrong file.

Comment: We need to see your node setup to be able to help any

Comment: I've had similar behavior.  Rendering with F12 seems to work for me as well to 'reboot' the compositor output.  I'm new here so I figure I'm missing something.  Can't wait to see a good answer.

Comment: If you don't hit F12 there will be no information for the compositor to work with.

Comment: uhhh. I don't understand. the composite never shows until everything is plugged in. It's like saying "this thing doesn't work when it's off". Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @Vince Scalia It is plugged in, but doesn't work, until I unplug it and plugit in again or turn off and back on node editor.

Comment: @cegaton It is not duplicate. I don't have problem previewing. I have problem getting result in render output (F12).

Comment: @JozefCulen do you have autorender enabled?

Comment: @cegaton No I don't.

Comment: I guess I was confused because there are no preview images on the render layer icons (they appear only after you render) in any case I can't reproduce your error http://i.stack.imgur.com/GLM4v.gif

Comment: Thank you. I will upload .blend after weekend. I have it in work.

Comment: Added blend file

Comment: ^that file doesn't have a node setup for the compositor

Comment: Sorry, I have uploaded wrong file. Link should be correct now.

Comment: in the bottom of the render tab there is "Post processing" contains "compositing" option which should be checked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To enable compositing go to **Post processing** in the **Render** tab of the **Properties** Panel and:

- check the **Compositing** option
- uncheck the **Sequencer** option

this will process the render result through the compositing pipeline if the compositing nodes are enabled.

[image: Compositing]

Comment: This is an answer for an old version, but in 3.1 both Compositing and Sequencer options still exist, albeit they are now in Output tab instead of Render tab. In 3.1 there is no need to uncheck Sequencer for Compositing to work.