# Compositor won't load image!

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image: Screenshot.]

The viewer node just shows a black picture. I've checked "Compositing" in render settings. Neither inputting the render result directly nor inputting an external image file seem to work. I'm just learning how to use the compositor and I don't know what to do. Help!

Edit: I'm using Blender 2.76.

[image]

Comment: Your image [isn't packed](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1337/1245) in the .blend file. However, it's seen that "Use Nodes" checkbox in the bottom of the Node Editor is turned off. Enable it and the nodes should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make composite nodes up and running, check two things:

1. Ensure the [**Compositing** option under **Post processing** in the **Render** tab is checked](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24126/1245).
2. Ensure the Compositing nodes are enabled. In the Node Editor, Compositing Nodes tab check *Use Nodes*:

   [image]