# How do I export from Compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I've set up all my nodes and connected the last noodle to the Composite node, but how do I then export the new image? The Render Result in the UV/Image Editor hasn't changed and I can't see a Save Image option or anything. Am I missing something or do I need to re-render?

Comment: Once Compositor is used you should see changes in the render result. If there aren't, try checking if compositing nodes are enabled; also try placing image editor and Nodes editor next to each other and run compositing ones more, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23999/compositor-result-wont-show. No need to re-render; it works atop of any image/render.

Comment: It depends: if you are rendering a single image just press F12 the image will be rendered and has to be saved as image from the UV/image editor. If  you are dealing with animation press Ctrl F12 to render and the animation will save using the settings on the Output section of the Properties window. Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6769/no-file-output-after-rendering

Answer (score 3):

It should work as Mr. Zak says, anyway you can create a viewer node in the compositor, then choose viewer in the UV/Image window and save the image.

I connected the composite output node to the original image to have the behaviour you described, maybe that was the problem?

[image]